# using data binding to get input for a list of items of various types

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my application I am trying to follow the MVVM. But I am stuck with a problem.
User inputs name of a particular table(say tab_1) that exists in DB and contains any number of columns. Each column can be any of the following datatypes - int,varchar,bool. I can get the list of column names and their types.
Is there any way (that follows MVVM pattern) through which I can can take input for each of the columns using data binding and save the data in the table tab_1?
The tables are generated at run time. so only when user input the name of the table, it is possible to know the actual number of columns and their corresponding data types.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the variation of the tables is fixed (like there is 5 tables to choose from and they wont be changed in runtime) you can make viewmodels for each of the table. Then inside View prepare data templates for each of these ViewModels (with target type match the viewmodel type).

If you don't know what kind of tables there are, I think you need to generate ViewModels and corresponding datatemplates in the runtime based on the table members. It should be easy since as you posted, there is fixed variation of the member types.

Comment: The number of tables and the number of columns in a table are known at run time only. So I guess, I need to generate viewmodels and corresponding data model at run time. If possible please explain with an example. Thank you in advance.